# NHibernate property change tracking

Tags: nhibernate

What is the best way to implement property change tracking with NHibernate.  I'm migrating an application from LINQ-to-SQL and am currently implementing it in the entity like so.

```
public class Task {

partial void OnLoaded() {
   OriginalTitle = Title;
}

public bool OriginalTitle { get; private set; }
public bool TitleChanged { get { return Title != OriginalTitle; } }

}
```

However, there is now OnLoaded event method in NHibernate.   Is there a way this code could be auto-generated somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with session event listener:
http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/creating-an-audit-log-using-nhibernate-events